same extrinsic hash but different transaction and transaction broadcast issue
Is it possible for different transactions to have the same txid? My address on Polkadot is
https://polkadot.subscan.io/account/16iAvH56VJWsZDU2cRZUPY9RPRcf5pvmB93PfpJ6fDx5Wvdq?tab=transfer
. Among them, 21511305-3 and 21511690-2 have the same txid, but my program only initiated the transaction 21511305-3. I don't know how 21511690-2 was triggered.
is it any possible reason for fullnode that transaction will broadcast twice for a while?
or what methods can we use to prevent unexpected transactions from being broadcast like this time?
